# Can Blight be cured with any kind of water?

Tags: noragami

In episode 2 of Noragami, we see that when Yato's hand gets blighted, he can remove the blight from his body with water from the Shrine he sleeps at.

[image: Blight cured with water]

However, in episode 9 Hiyori successfully removes her blight with water from Kofuku house. Are there any criteria for the water that is used for cleansing a blight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said on the [Wikia article on Blight](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Blight):

> **Blight mark without phantom eyes can be cleansed by washing it away using purifying water obtained from shrines or natural springs.** This method only works for a God that is injured by a phantom’s attack or a soul that is infected from a wounded God.

Even though Kofuku does not have a shrine, I guess the water at her home qualifies as "purified" owing to it being her abode, and her being as famous/worshipped as the [Seven Gods of Fortune](http://noragami.wikia.com/wiki/Seven_Gods_of_Fortune).

Either that, or she has stored some "purifying water" at her home for dealing with blights like in the case of Yato.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot what episode it is but Daikoku mentioned that the water they get in the house is straight from the shrine.